# log4j not printing logs in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, logging, automation, log4j

I try to logging automation log using log4j. logs file created but logs not print in log file

log4j.properties File

```
#Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=debug, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/home/rohit/akd_e2e/src/test/resources/Logs/Selenium.log
log4j.appender.file.maxFileSize=5000KB
log4j.appender.file.maxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
#do not append the old file. Create a new log file everytime
log4j.appender.file.Append=false


#Application Logs
log4j.logger.devpinoyLogger=DEBUG, dest1
log4j.appender.dest1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.dest1.maxFileSize=5000KB
log4j.appender.dest1.maxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.dest1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dest1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %c %m%n
log4j.appender.dest1.File=/home/rohit/akd_e2e/src/test/resources/Logs/Application.log
#do not append the old file. Create a new log file everytime
log4j.appender.dest1.Append=false
```

Set Driver file

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


public class Set_Driver {
public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("devpinoyLogger");
```

pom.xml where I add dependencies of log4j

```
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: It looks fine, and it should work if you have placed the log4j.properties file under test/resources path. What is "devpinoyLogger" and what are you logging? Please add those lines as well, so that it would help to get the proper solution.

Comment: Just want to make sure we're not misunderstanding something: What are you expecting to see in the logfile? Is there a log-Statement in Set_Driver  that's not showing up? If yes, could you post that

Comment: @SoorajSathianandan I want logging application logs so after automation complete, I can easily share log file with the developer so it easy debugs any issue.

Comment: @Simon what is log-statement? I just want logs all type log when automation running.

Comment: It print only some error :

03/12/2019 12:54:03 DEBUG Set_Driver:36 - Start website admitkard
03/12/2019 12:54:24 DEBUG cache:45 - Couldn't find template in cache for "v3html/v3-html-index.ftl"("en", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.

Comment: @rohit, I tried with your log4j.properties, maven dependency and the Logger from your Driver class. It is working fine and it is logging properly. Just to make sure, are you logging each steps like _log.info("App is initialized")_, _log.fatal("App is not initialized: ")_

Comment: @SoorajSathianandan log4j using for logged two type logs. 1. manual log and 2. application log, so manual log working fine but I want to log application log.

Comment: @rohit, If you are logging the steps correctly, then it should work for both Selenium.log and Application.log. And you are not providing the answers for the questions I'm asking in comments which won't help.

Comment: @SoorajSathianandan "devpinoyLogeer" by mistake. I used     "public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Set_Driver.class);" in Set_Driver file. and I want to log all type logs like which Http connection, application workflow

Answer (score 0):

How are you passing in the log4j file to the application? Maybe you need to specify it as `file:/home/usr/log4j.properties` (note the **file**)

Comment: where we pass log4j file in the application?

Comment: @RohitGupta Did you find the solution for this ? I am observing same issue. Kindly let me know what the issue was and how you resolved. it will help me also .

Answer (score 0):

So I just faced this Issue. On replacing the selenium dependency from **3.141.59** to **2.53.1** the logs started appearing again.

The selenium version 3 is not compatible with log4j I guess. Still not sure, But It sure did consume a lot of time on figuring this out.

Comment: i reduced the org.seleniumhq.selenium version from 3.141.59 to 2.53.1 still doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

Working fine after changing selenium dependency from 3.141.59 to 2.53.1.
selenium logs are coming with 2.53.1 dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. I had even tried 3.141.59, 3.5.3 and 2.53.1 it didn't work for me.
After changing selenium dependency to 4.0.0 it started working for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After Logger class object creation, do use this method, helps you to configure the log4j.properties file

```
public class Set_Driver {
    public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("devpinoyLogger");
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("c:\\path\\log4j.properties");
}
```